# Query not using an index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am running a query against 2 tables and it's not using the index for some reason.  I can't figure it our for the life of me.

Here are my tables: `table1` and `table2`.  Table 1 is a list of categories with 154 rows.  The table structure for table 1 looks like this:

```
category_id (int11) - also has an index on it
name (varchar30) - also has an index on it
urltext (text)
nametext (text)

category_id     name    urltext   nametext
1           category1    blahblah     blahblah
2           category2    blahblah     blahblah
3           category3    blahblah     blahblah
4           category4    blahblah     blahblah
etc to rows
154           category154    blahblah     blahblah
```

Table 2 has 1+ million rows, and relates products categories.  The table field structure looks like this:

```
row_id (bigint11) - also has an index
category_id (int3) - also has an index
product_id (int9) - also has an index
```

The data in table 2 looks like this:

```
row_id     category_id     product_id 
1               1            123456
2               4            123456
3               17            456789
4               42            456789
5               7            456789
6               88            888555
```

Here's my query:

```
select * 
from table2 
INNER JOIN table1 
ON table2.category_id=table1.category_id 
where table2.product_id = 123456;
```

And now, when I run an explain on this query:

```
id   select_type  table type  possible_keys     key       key_len  ref                 rows  Extra
1    simple       table1 ALL    PRIMARY          NULL      NULL     NULL                 154
1    simple       table2 ref    product_id,...   poduct_id  10      category_id, const   1     Using Where
```

Any product usually only relates to between 1 and 4 different categories.  So, you'd think that if the index was being used correctly, instead of seeing 154 rows for table1 in the explain results, you'd see a max of 4.

I originally had table1.name set as `text` instead of `varchar(30)`, but still the results have not changed.  This wouldn't matter so much if this were a randomly used query, but this query is getting hit many tens of thousands of times daily.

What am I doing wrong here that this query is not using the available indexes to massively reduce the number of rows?

I hope I provided the correct information.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be reformatted as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.category_id = table1.category_id
WHERE table2.product_id = 123456
```

To make it fast, following indexes should exist:

```
table1(category_id)
```

to make lookup by `table1.category_id` fast.

And

```
table2(category_id, product_id)
```

or

```
table2(product_id, category_id)
```

This multi-column (compound) index will work to satisfy both `JOIN` condition and `WHERE` condition.

Note that having separate indexes on `product_id` and `category_id` is not enough. But, if you have compound index on `(category_id, product_id)`, you can delete index on `(category_id)`, unless it was unique index (like primary key).

Comment: Hi, I added that compound index and yet I'm getting the exact same results in the EXPLAIN

Comment: try to `OPTIMIZE` both table1 and table2 - it may change query planner selection of best query plan